# Postgres-xc installing error `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, postgresql

I am facing problem when I try to install postgres-xc from terminal.

`badar:~$ sudo apt-get install postgres-xc`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgres-xc : Depends: postgres-xc-client but it is not going to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`badar:~$ sudo apt-get install postgres-xc`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
postgres-xc : Depends: postgres-xc-client but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken package
```

Comment: try this `sudo apt-get -f install postgres-xc`

Comment: this is the problem now 

`W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/ trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.getdeb.net_ubuntu_dists_trusty getdeb_apps_binary-i386_Packages)`
`W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbun u_14.04/  Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/download.opensuse.org_repositories_home:_colom oem_xUbuntu%5f14.04_Packages)`
`W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems`
` E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: please run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: please use __your space bar to indent(4) your results__ to get the same format you see